# Как сделать синхронизацию двух полей select?

Tags: javascript, html, dom

Имеется два поля select c 4 опциями в каждом.

- `Вариант 1` выбран по умолчанию `(selected)` и включает в себя только `option 1`.
- `Вариант 2` даёт возможность выбора `option 1` и `option 2`.
- `Вариант 3` даёт возможность выбора `option 1`, `option 2` и `option 3`.
- Без вариантов даёт возможность выбрать только `No options`, все остальные опции в селекте должны иметь атрибут `disabled`.

```html
<select id="var_numbers">
  <option value="1" selected>Вариант 1</option>
  <option value="2">Вариант 2</option>
  <option value="3">Вариант 3</option>
  <option value="0">Без вариантов</option>
</select>


<select id="options">
  <option value="1" selected>option 1</option>
  <option value="2" disabled>option 2</option>
  <option value="3" disabled>option 3</option>
  <option value="0" disabled>No options</option>
</select>
```

Comment: ну дак вы начните, а мы поможем. повесьте обработчик изменения на первый селект. получите внутри выбранное значение. Создайте массив/объект, в котором будут установлены соответствия пунктов второго селекта.

Comment: Спасибо, что навели на мысль. Хотелось бы получить код, чтобы он не зависел от количества опций, т.е. был бы универсальным при любом их количестве

Comment: @russian-stan Сразу сказать нельзя было?

Comment: @Alexandr Maliovaniy , полагаю, что универсальность и максимальная простота кода - хорошая практика и это должно быть изначальной установкой

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```js
var opt = document.getElementById("options");
document.getElementById("var_numbers").addEventListener("change", function() {
  var currentVal = this.value;
  if (currentVal == 0) {
    for (var i = 0; i < opt.children.length; i++) {
      opt.children[i].disabled = true;
    }
    opt.children[opt.children.length - 1].disabled = false;
    opt.children[opt.children.length - 1].selected = true;
  } else {
    for (var i = 0; i < opt.children.length; i++) {
      if (i < currentVal) {
        opt.children[i].disabled = false;
      } else {
        opt.children[i].disabled = true;
      }
    }
    opt.children[0].selected = true;
  }
});
```

```html
<select id="var_numbers">
  <option value="1" selected>Вариант 1</option>
  <option value="2">Вариант 2</option>
  <option value="3">Вариант 3</option>
  <option value="0">Без вариантов</option>
</select>


<select id="options">
  <option value="1" selected>option 1</option>
  <option value="2" disabled>option 2</option>
  <option value="3" disabled>option 3</option>
  <option value="0" disabled>No options</option>
</select>
```

Comment: Надо менять опцию на первую активную, если она становится неактивной.

Comment: Адаптивный код(Вероде бы)